# Moving data from sql to nosql with azure data factory

Tags: sql, mongodb, azure-data-factory

A simple question: I can't find any specific documentation that says that you can move data from a sql db (on-prem) to a nosql sb (mongodb) using Azure Data Factory.
Is that possible? Is there any documentation about it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a connector in ADF for MongoDB or Atlas MongoDB that you can use as a destination.
Here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties

Since your source is on-prem SQL server, you may need to use self hosted integration runtime to be able to connect to it (because it's inside the company firewall).
Here is the coumentation to installing it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory